# Spring Controller and Jquery Ajax are unable to convert Json string to Object

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have been struggling with the Jquery ajax post data into Spring controller as @RequestBody.

I was able to send the JSON string and capture the JSON string in controller. But, unable to send JSON String from jquery ajax  to controller [which is unable to convert as Object].

Below is code snippet:

```
 **Ajax Call:**   


          function postLoad(){
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : "ajaxhai.do",
                    contentType : "application/json",
                    cache : false,
                    data : responseObject, **//json-String**
                    dataType :"html",
                    success : function(data, textStatus) {
                        console.log("POST success");
                        $("#ajaxContent").html(data);
                    },
                    error : function(request, status, error) {
                        console.log("failed" + error);
                    }
                });
            }
```

// responseObject initialised:

```
            <c:if test='${not empty ajitems}'>
                var responseObject = JSON.stringify('${ajitems}');
            </c:if>  
   // ${ajitems}--> is the model attribute and setting it in javascript to //send it back to controller through ajax call

    //Controller:
    @RequestMapping(value = "ajaxhai.do", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json") **//unable to convert to requestBody**
        public  String testAjaxPost(@RequestBody AjaxDto[] ajaxRes, Model model,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

            System.out.println(ajaxRes);

            return "ajaxform";
        }
```

I have jackson dependency as well in pom:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

It is always saying :

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8080/testSpringmvc-1.0/ajaxhai.do 400 (Bad Request)
```

But when I change the controller in the following way, it is working like charm:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ajaxhai.do", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")**//Please note : here it is String and not Object[]**
    public  String testAjaxPost(@RequestBody String ajaxRes, Model model,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        System.out.println(ajaxRes);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TestAjaxDto[] mcArray = gson.fromJson(ajaxRes, TestAjaxDto[].class);
        List<TestAjaxDto> mcList = new ArrayList<TestAjaxDto>(Arrays.asList(mcArray));
        System.out.println(mcList);
        return "ajaxform";
    }
```

what is that I'm missing here? I have tried all the possibilities for auto json conversion still no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You mentioned dataType as html in ajax request. I think it should be `application/json` or just remove it.

Comment: @VijendraKulhade dataType is meant to be the return type expected right. Even I gave it a try but still the response received is same /*RequestURL:http://localhost:8080/testSpringmvc-1.0/ajaxhai.do
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:[::1]:8080*/

Comment: You are right I got confused with dataType and contentType.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your json which you are trying to send when you are expecting array in controller. There is something wrong with the json. 
Also check if you have registered `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` I assume you should have done that.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="objectMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"
                  p:autoDetectFields="false"
                  p:autoDetectGettersSetters="false"
                  p:failOnEmptyBeans="false"
                  p:indentOutput="true">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Here is the example which works fine. Ajax request

```
var requestObject = [{"product_Name":"One Product","descripction":"Essentials","category":null,"price":"100.00","mfg_Date":null,"image":null},
    {"product_Name":"two Product","descripction":"Essentials 2","category":null,"price":"120.00","mfg_Date":null,"image":null}];
    $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : "services/product",
            cache : false,
            contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data : JSON.stringify(requestObject),//json-String**
            dataType :"application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success : function(data, textStatus) {
                console.log("POST success"+data);
               /* $("#ajaxContent").html(data);*/
            },
            error : function(request, status, error) {
                console.log("failed" + error);
            }
        });
```

Here is the controller which accept this request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product",produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE},
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<List<Product>> createProduct(@RequestBody  Product[] products) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Product>>(Arrays.asList(products), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```